# Javascript onFocus event fires continuously in Google Chrome - Is it a bug?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I wrote a little javascript function that checks for a cookie when onFocus is triggered in a form input text field.

If the cookie is found, then a dialog pops up welcoming the person back to the site.

But in Chrome, each time a dialog is closed a new one pops up. I suppose it's because the text field is still technically 'Focused'.

But this problem does not occur in Firefox or IE9.

I solved it in Chrome by adding in the lines that I currently have commented. But what I would like to know is if this behavior is considered to be a bug or normal behavior, and if it is normal then why do the other browsers behave differently?

Here is the javascript code sample:

```
//var checked = 0;
var checkIt = getCookie('cia_db');
function checkCookie() {

//  if(checked == 0) {

        if(checkIt == 'logged_in') {
            alert('Welcome back to CIA headquarters.');
            //return true;
        }
    //}
        //checked++;
}
```

And here's the html:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="" method="get">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="smeegle" size="15" onfocus="checkCookie();">
```

etc...

Comment: I would think its a bug, since `onfocus` is supposed to fire `when an element gets focus`. It does not say 'as long as an element is in focus`. Quite the opposite to `onfocus` is `onblur` which is defined as `fires when an element loses focus` and `onblur` only fires once.

Comment: I think it is a bug also. Not fixed in Chrome 17. Maybe you should file a bug report. http://jsfiddle.net/x2Zvz/

Comment: @mrtsherman I wouldn't call this a bug. Try using `console.log` instead of an `alert` and it will work perfectly fine because when the alert is 'okay-ed', Chrome returns focus to the `input` element, firing the `onfocus` event handler in an endless loop.

Comment: Are you really doing this? Displaying an alert that says 'Welcome back to CIA headquarters.' Bad idea, unless you want the users to be pissed off at the website.

Comment: Um, yes, I am displaying it, at which point the user is redirected to cia.gov. I think Amaan and Dr Molle are probably right, but the fact remains that only Chrome has this behavior. Why aren't Firefox and IE9 returning focus to the input field and creating an infinite loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The field will lose the focus() when the alert appears, chrome gives the focus back to the input when the alert  is closed, so onfocus fires again.

Other browsers may give the focus to the window after closing the alert, so onfocus will not fire again.
I wouldn't call it bug, it's a different behaviour.

Solution:
Remove the focus before the alert()

Comment: +1: You got the problem correctly, but a better solution is not to display alerts when handling the onfocus event. Display your message in a less intrusive way. Removing the focus changes what the user was trying to do.

Comment: The focus behavior can be a bit of an issue if you are calling from a button or handler with an accesskey and onfocus attributes.  Google Chrome Developers should likely think about verifying the caller does not have an accesskey defined with an onfocus as this can easily cause loops with javascript dialog boxes (alert/confirm/prompt).  As Juan Mendes mentions avoiding the javascript dialog boxes will assist, but this behavior interferes with accesskey functionality which ties directly to the onfocus event when triggered.